# How to download twitter bootstrap excluding glyphicons to use font-awesome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

How do I download bootstrap excluding glyphicons?

I want to use font-awesome and I want to call it internally from a directory on my site. Currently, I've only found how to call external links, but I do not always have access to the internet, and if my internet connection is **down** I can't test on my localhost.

I currently do it like this:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I have looked at the stack-overflow questions regarding bootstrap and font-awesome, but it recommends external links, which would not work for me.

Comment: the href in those links are 'protocol independent' but still refer to a file hosted on the web, you could always just download those files, just append `http:` to the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you can and should use a CDN for the delivery of both [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) and [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), you can also download them directly by appending `http:` to the links that you're referencing from [bootstrapcdn.com](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

**Storing the files locally by default**

In your case, visiting the following URLs will allow you to download/store them locally (depending on your OS, download method and versions of bootstrap/font-awesome required):

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css

You could then store them in local directories (renaming them where needed):

```
<link href="/path/to/assets/bootstrap-2.3.2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/path/to/assets/font-awesome-3.2.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Conditional resource loading**

Given that you'd like the ability to develop locally as well as in a staging/production environment, there are a number of JS libraries which would allow you to *systematically check* if external resources are available and if not, default to a local version instead.

For example, you could use a library like [yepnopejs](http://yepnopejs.com/) (no affiliation) in the following way:

```js
yepnope([{
  load: 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css',
  complete: function () {
    if (!window.jQuery) {
      yepnope('path/to/css/font-awesome-3.2.1.css');
    }
  }
}]);
```

There are other libraries that do similar, but [yepnopejs](http://yepnopejs.com/) works particularly well. You could write your own JS loader or also achieve the same result using scripting/programming languages other than Javascript too.

Development should be *portable* and conditional resource loading offers a way of achieving it.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, that is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Boostrap Customize section [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html), uncheck "Icons" from Base CSS and click "Customize and Download"

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the default bootstrap icons and download the font-awesome resources and include them in your bootstrap project folder.

Then reference the font-awesome css files the font formats that you want to use, and you're good to go.